# How can you call methods on Object if it is a constructor?

Tags: javascript

The Object object is defined as a constructor. However, I am able to call methods on it like Object.create(), Object.freeze(), Object.assign(), etc...  I can also create a new object by typing "var foo = new Object()".

So if Object is a constructor, how am I able to call methods directly on it?

That has always confused me.

Comment: It's a static method.

Comment: A constructor is just a function, and all functions are objects. All objects can have methods placed on them. Ergo, a constructor can have methods.

Comment: What is confusing? in most object oriented languages, classes can have class methods.

Comment: I am guessing the constructor looks like this: function Object(){//constructor} and the methods like create() would be like Object.create = function(){//native code for create}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors can have properties themselves, too. In modern syntax, these are called static methods. For example:

```js
class Foo {
  static fooRelatedFn() {
    console.log('foo related function running');
  }
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
  }
}

Foo.fooRelatedFn();
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar);
```

The same thing can be done using conventional syntax, simply by assigning to a property of the constructor:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 'bar';
}
Foo.fooRelatedFn = function() {
  console.log('foo related function running');
}

Foo.fooRelatedFn();
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Comment: YES, YES, YES! That is what I was wondering, how it was done the earlier way. I understand now. I knew the create() method for example was not part of its prototype. I appreciate it.